# Search Term Finder in Array

Tags: java

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Finder {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    String [] names = new String[5];
    String searchTerm = "";

    for (int i = 0; i <= names.length - 1; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
        names[i] = scnr.next();
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Enter a name to search for: ");
    searchTerm = scnr.next();

    for (int i = 0; i <= names.length - 1; i++) {
        if (searchTerm.equals(names[i])) {
            System.out.println(searchTerm + " found!!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(searchTerm + " not found!!");
        }
    }  

}

}
```

I am working on the if/else statement in the second for loop and when I add the else part of the statement, it returns:

Enter a name: Luke

Enter a name: Kassy

Enter a name: Chloe

Enter a name: Jon

Enter a name: Jake

**Enter a name to search for: Chloe**

Chloe not found!!

Chloe not found!!

Chloe found!!

Chloe not found!!

Chloe not found!!

I am not sure why it just doesn't say "Chloe found!!" instead of what it says?

Comment: put your else statement outside the foor loop

Comment: Try using `nextLine` instead of `next`

Comment: That worked! Thank you for your help

Comment: wait now when i put the statement outside the loop, it comes up with one "found" statement and one "not found statement"

Comment: Check out my answer, the problem occurs because you are printing out a statement for each element of the names array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your code now, when you're looping to find the element "Chloe" in the `names` array, you're going through each element and printing a statement out no matter what. "Chloe" is `names[2]` but your loop checks `names[0]` and `names[1]` first. Since they are not "Chloe", it will print "Chloe not found" (the else part of your if statement). Once it gets to `names[2]`, it will then have found "Chloe" and the if part of your if statement will be executed, printing out "Chloe found". However your loop does not stop there, so the loop will look at `names[3]` and `names[4]` and print out "Chloe not found" because none of them equals "Chloe". The simple fix is to only print "Chloe not found" when the loop ends without finding "Chloe" and to only print "Chloe found" when in the middle of the loop, "Chloe" is found. There are many ways to do this but one way I propose is using a boolean variable to check after the loop is done to see if "Chloe" was found or not.

```
boolean termFound = false;
for (int i = 0; i <= names.length - 1; i++) {
        if (searchTerm.equals(names[i])) {
            System.out.println(searchTerm + " found!!");
            termFound = true;
            break;//if term is found, you can break out of the loop early
        }

}  
if(!termFound){ //if searchTerm was not found
        System.out.println(sertTerm + " not found!!");
}
```

Comment: The boolean variable is a big help!